# Why throw an Error object instead of something else?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling

In Mozilla's explanation of [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) it is explained that `throw` accepts an expression. Usually you see [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) objects being thrown on exceptions, so I was wondering if there are any downsides to throwing something else (like a string or number) instead of an error object.

Comment: Gives a more accurate description of the Error. If throwing an Error Object it shows up as an Error in the Client's console as an Error.

Comment: That totally depends on what you want to do with the thrown error.

Comment: Throwing a string (any non-error object) will still display an error in the clients console: http://imgur.com/5kERF0N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a concrete answer, but having a standard object where you know it will contain certain properties like `message` is handy and consistent makes it easier for the rest of your application to respond accordingly.

Also if those errors bubble to the top without being caught, then having a service like Loggly (or similar) in place to log those errors offsite, the standard error object makes it easier for such a service to create meaningful data for you

Comment: Ok, so basically it's standardisation, where it's useful if you want others to interact with the error, if I understand correctly.

Comment: There are probably a lot of reasons - but standardisation would be the big one for me. It's an interesting question though! Because you still get a stack trace and error output regardless. So yeah, I believe standardisation is the biggie